# Class exception when trying to move a email using the spring integration message payload

Tags: spring-integration

Hi I have configured the default filter as below and if some emails have a certain subject or from address I try to move them to specific folders using java mail api as below:

Filter implementation:

```
@Bean(name = ImapAdaptersUtil.DEFAULT_FILTER_BEAN_NAME)
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION)
public MessageSelector defaultFilter() {
    return message -> {
        if (message.getPayload() instanceof MimeMessage) {
            try {
                String from = Optional.ofNullable(((InternetAddress) ((MimeMessage) message.getPayload()).getFrom()[0]).getAddress()).orElse(GeneralConst.EMPTY_STRING);
                String subject = Optional.ofNullable(((MimeMessage) message.getPayload()).getSubject()).orElse(GeneralConst.EMPTY_STRING);

                if (!from.matches(DELIVERY_ERROR_FROM)
                        && !from.matches(SPAM_FROM)
                        && !subject.matches(DELIVERY_ERROR_SUBJECT)
                        && !subject.matches(OUT_OF_OFFICE)
                        && !subject.matches(SPAM_SUBJECT)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MessagingException me) {
                throw new ApplicationBusinessException(ApplicationBusinessException.ApplicationBusinessExceptionType.FUNCTIONAL_VIOLATION,
                        "Could not filter incoming email: " + me.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            this.moveMessage(((MimeMessage) message.getPayload()));
        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            throw new ApplicationBusinessException(ApplicationBusinessException.ApplicationBusinessExceptionType.FUNCTIONAL_VIOLATION,
                    "Could not move incoming email: " + me.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

Move to folder implementation:

```
private void moveMessage(MimeMessage message) throws MessagingException {
    Folder folder = message.getFolder();
    Store store = folder.getStore();
    Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
    for (Folder folder1 : folders) {
        LOGGER.info("folder name {}", folder1.getName());
    }

    Folder deliveryErrorFolder = store.getFolder("Delivery error");
    if (!deliveryErrorFolder.exists()) {
        if (deliveryErrorFolder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES)) {
            deliveryErrorFolder.setSubscribed(true);
            move(message, folder, deliveryErrorFolder);
            LOGGER.info("Delivery error created");
        }
    } else {
        move(message, folder, deliveryErrorFolder);
    }
}

private void move(MimeMessage message, Folder folder, Folder spamFolder) throws MessagingException {
    List<javax.mail.Message> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    tempList.add(message);
    javax.mail.Message[] tempMessageArray = tempList.toArray(new javax.mail.Message[0]);
    folder.copyMessages(tempMessageArray, spamFolder);
    LOGGER.info("message moved");
}
```

ImapMailReceiver configured as an Integration flow :

```
public static IntegrationFlow getImapAdapterIntegrationFlow(String imapsUrl, MessageSelector filter, QueueChannelSpec channelSpec) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(imapsUrl)
                   
                            .userFlag("testSIUserFlag")
                            .simpleContent(false)
                            .autoCloseFolder(false)
                            .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true)
                            .javaMailProperties(getPropertiesBuilderConsumer()),
                    e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                            .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000)))
            .filter(filter)
            .channel(channelSpec)
            .get();
}
```

I get this exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage cannot be cast to class com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage (org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver$IntegrationMimeMessage and com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at com.sun.mail.imap.Utility.toMessageSet(Utility.java:85)
```

Comment: Where is that `defaultFilter()` is used? How you originally get mail messages into your flow? Would you mind to share an `ImapMailReceiver` configuration, please?

Comment: Hi Artem, I updated my question. The integration flows are getting registered dynamically. I pass the filter as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... What you are looking for is available starting with version `5.4`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html#mail-inbound

> Starting with version 5.4, it is possible now to return a MimeMessage as is without any conversion or eager content loading. This functionality is enabled with this combination of options: no headerMapper provided, the simpleContent property is false and the autoCloseFolder property is false.

So, all good in your config - only what you need to to upgrade your project to the latest Spring Integration. Directly with the `5.4.5` or via respective latest Spring Boot.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the headerMapper before and the class cast exception was thrown. I removed it from the question

Comment: I have fully edited my answer. Sorry, there is not workaround for your current `5.3.6` version: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3356

Comment: Can I use it with spring boot version : 2.2.0.RELEASE? I'm getting this error :  o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
 at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:330)

Comment: You can try. Although even `5.3.x` was wrong for that Spring Boot version... You definitely need to consider to upgrade the whole Spring Boot version to the latest

Comment: I tried it and it's not working. I will consider upgrading the spring boot version. Thank you!

Comment: I get this exception: 2021-03-26 20:26:36.164 ERROR 14444 --- [n-scheduling-16] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
 at org.springframework.integration.mail.AbstractMailReceiver.connectStoreIfNecessary(AbstractMailReceiver.java:330)

Comment: That's the problem with not upgrading the whole Spring Boot: you probably have specified the version for `spring-integration-mail` dependency, but `spring-integration-core` inherits its version from Spring Boot, which is not `5.4.5`.

Comment: I will try this in a sample project as I need to change a lot of things updating the version for now.

Comment: All good with spring integration 5.4.5, thank you!